# How to verify the password in PHPExcel generated ".xls" file?

Tags: php, phpexcel, password-protection, phpexcel-1.8.0

I am generating `excel` files with extension `.xls` using `PHPExcel` library. The excel file is generating. I am using **password protection** for the document and made only some fields editable. I am doing an `Export Import` mechanism. It is perfectly working now and I need to add some modification.

**My question is**

**Is it possible to verify the password I given to protect the document? So that I can check it at the time of import**

**For example**

If I protect the document using

```
$sheet -> getProtection() -> setPassword('MyPassword');
```

Is there any function like below for checking the password?

```
$newsheet -> getProtection() -> verifyPassword('MyPassword');
```

Any help could be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not well versed in PHPExcel, but could you not try to load it in PHPExcel again separately and attempt an edit with the password?

Comment: @SArnab, Thank you for the consideration. But I don't want to edit it. I just need a verification of the password.

Comment: What do you mean by “validation”? Your question reads if you just wanted to check that the `setPassword` method actually works? If so - why? Do you have any reason to doubt it?

Comment: @CBroe, Sorry for the typo. I need a verification method. I can download a protected excel and upload it via another interface. For ensure that it is the same file, I just need to verify the password.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use

```
$hash = $sheet->getProtection()->getPassword(); // returns a hash
$valid = ($hash === PHPExcel_Shared_PasswordHasher::hashPassword($password));

if($valid) {
    //
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Let me check with it.